# How to set due date based on number of dates out from event

Tags: datetime

I am building a website for planning events. Each event is in its own space to separate groups. These events are planned almost identically. For example Invitations need to be sent out 42 days before every event. 
What I would like to do is calculate the due date for tasks based on the event date minus the days before the event the task needs to be completed. I know I can do this by hand but since there are 100ish tasks and about 15 events a year, I would like it to be automated.

Ex.
"A Task" is due 30 days before event date.

Event 1 is April 30 so "A Task" is due April 1
Event 2 is June 30 so "A Task" is due June 1

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could use Computed Field module and a bit of coding for the calculations. https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field